# QtCreator shuts down after start

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Until yesterday qtcreator worked fine but since today after starting the window shortly opens up and then shuts down immediately. I tried some stuff to fix it but the error persists. 
I am using Qt version 5.9.5.
When starting qtcreator from terminal i get:

```
> Warning: No kit '{-some number-}' found. Continuing. SOFT ASSERT:
> "!tcd.tcs.isEmpty()" in file
> /build/qtcreator-4mibqh/qtcreator-4.5.2/src/plugins/cmakeprojectmanager/cmakeprojectimporter.cpp,
> line 336 SOFT ASSERT: "!tcd.tcs.isEmpty()" in file
> /build/qtcreator-4mibqh/qtcreator-4.5.2/src/plugins/cmakeprojectmanager/cmakeprojectimporter.cpp,
> line 336 SOFT ASSERT: "k" in file
> /build/qtcreator-4mibqh/qtcreator-4.5.2/src/plugins/projectexplorer/targetsettingspanel.cpp,
> line 315 SOFT ASSERT: "k" in file
> /build/qtcreator-4mibqh/qtcreator-4.5.2/src/plugins/projectexplorer/targetsettingspanel.cpp,
> line 315 SOFT ASSERT: "k" in file
> /build/qtcreator-4mibqh/qtcreator-4.5.2/src/plugins/projectexplorer/targetsettingspanel.cpp,
> line 315 SOFT ASSERT: "k" in file
> /build/qtcreator-4mibqh/qtcreator-4.5.2/src/plugins/projectexplorer/targetsettingspanel.cpp,
> line 315 SOFT ASSERT: "k" in file
> /build/qtcreator-4mibqh/qtcreator-4.5.2/src/plugins/projectexplorer/targetsettingspanel.cpp,
> line 315 SOFT ASSERT: "k" in file
> /build/qtcreator-4mibqh/qtcreator-4.5.2/src/plugins/projectexplorer/targetsettingspanel.cpp,
> line 315 SOFT ASSERT: "!tcd.tcs.isEmpty()" in file
> /build/qtcreator-4mibqh/qtcreator-4.5.2/src/plugins/cmakeprojectmanager/cmakeprojectimporter.cpp,
> line 336 SOFT ASSERT: "!tcd.tcs.isEmpty()" in file
> /build/qtcreator-4mibqh/qtcreator-4.5.2/src/plugins/cmakeprojectmanager/cmakeprojectimporter.cpp,
> line 336 Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Any idea about how to solve this issue?

Comment: "I tried some stuff to fix it but the error persists." What are the things have you tried? Did you do any update recently such as updating the OS or Qt or activate a new virus guard?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-22702 . Looks like a known issue.